# Matrix with for loop in R

Tags: r, matrix

i have the following code in R

```
    M <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(27:45), ncol = 2)
colnames(M) <- c("Age", "Whole Life Insurance Benefits")
i<-1
for (i in seq(27, 45, by=1)) {
  M[i,1]<- i
  M[i,2]<- Axn(actuarialtable = lc.lifetable, x=i)
  i<-i+1
}
M
```

and when i run it i have the error `subscript out of bounds`
but if i change `nrow=length(0:45)` it runs without errors but i have a lot of NAs in my matrix. Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your code :

> **1.**  with **`nrow=length(27:45)`** you just have **19** rows, but your sequence in **`if`** function starts from **27** that not exist
>   at all in your matrix, you must start it from **1**.
>
> **2.** when you used **`if`** function it sums counter by **1** automatically, if you insert **`i<-i+1`** in your loop, the counter
>   sums by **2**, and also you can use **`1:19`** instead of
>   **`seq(1,19,by=1)`**

Here is correct and simple code :

```
M <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(27:45), ncol = 2)
colnames(M) <- c("Age", "Whole Life Insurance Benefits")
i<-1
for (i in 1:length(27:45)) {
  M[i,1]<- i
  M[i,2]<- Axn(actuarialtable = lc.lifetable, x=i)
}
M
```

Comment: Actually, the sequence starts from 1, what if i need to start from 27?

Comment: in that case you must create your matrix with more than 27 rows and then in your "if" function set to 27:your rows count. Don't forget the upvote ! tnx ! @user183722